# super.init() error: must call a designated initializer of the superclass "x"

Tags: swift, inheritance, initialization, designated-initializer

I created a basic custom class inheriting from an existing one as follows:

[image: Screenshot of my custom subclass]

As you can see, it gives me the basic error of the designated initializer of the superclass. However, I did use it! The superclass has only one `init()` with no arguments.

How can I fix that problem?

Comment: `The superclass has only one init() with no arguments.` are you sure?

Comment: Please post code in your question as text, not as an image. Images can't be referenced or searched and are harder to read.

Comment: Assuming `WhirlyGlobeViewController` is a `UIViewController`, your question is a duplicate of the linked post.

Comment: Yes. I asked the developper of the super class. He was sure at 100%.

Comment: Thank you @JAL. It works now, but I'm not sure I understand the procedure. When you don't have any designated initializer with arguments from the superclass, do you need to go to a higher level in the hierarchy and use their designated initializer?